# c# Stream progress just like .DownloadProgressChanged

Tags: c#, stream, zip, webclient

So i have the following code:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
Stream data = webClient.OpenRead("http://awesomeurl.com/file.zip");
UnzipFromStream(data, @"c:/dir/");
```

And i would like to have the data of that stream in a progress bar, just like if you would use WebClient with .DownloadProgressChanged

I cant however seem to figure out how to make it work...

**Please note:** i am using [ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Zip-Samples)

**UPDATE #1.1**

Ok, i managed to get the following code to work (it downloads and unzips + the complete msg is shown), however the progress bar is not updating:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // first, we need to get the exact size (in bytes) of the file we are downloading
        Uri url = new Uri(filename);
        System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
        System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        response.Close();
        // gets the size of the file in bytes
        Int64 iSize = response.ContentLength;

        // keeps track of the total bytes downloaded so we can update the progress bar
        Int64 iRunningByteTotal = 0;

        string outFolder = folder;

        // use the webclient object to download the file
        using (System.Net.WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            // open the file at the remote URL for reading
            using (System.IO.Stream zipStream = webClient.OpenRead(filename))
            {
                ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(zipStream);
                ZipEntry zipEntry = zipInputStream.GetNextEntry();
                while (zipEntry != null)
                {
                    String entryFileName = zipEntry.Name;
                    // to remove the folder from the entry:- entryFileName = Path.GetFileName(entryFileName);
                    // Optionally match entrynames against a selection list here to skip as desired.
                    // The unpacked length is available in the zipEntry.Size property.

                    // Manipulate the output filename here as desired.
                    String fullZipToPath = Path.Combine(outFolder, entryFileName);
                    string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullZipToPath);
                    if (directoryName.Length > 0)
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName);

                    // Unzip file in buffered chunks. This is just as fast as unpacking to a buffer the full size
                    // of the file, but does not waste memory.
                    // The "using" will close the stream even if an exception occurs.
                    using (FileStream streamWriter = File.Create(fullZipToPath))
                    {

                        int iByteSize = 0;
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[iSize]; // 4K is optimum

                        StreamUtils.Copy(zipInputStream, streamWriter, buffer);

                        while ((iByteSize = zipStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                        {

                            iRunningByteTotal += iByteSize;

                            // calculate the progress out of a base "100"
                            double dIndex = (double)(iRunningByteTotal);
                            double dTotal = (double)iSize;
                            double dProgressPercentage = (dIndex / dTotal);
                            int iProgressPercentage = (int)(dProgressPercentage * 100);

                            // update the progress bar
                            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(iProgressPercentage);
                        }
                    }
                    zipEntry = zipInputStream.GetNextEntry();
                }
            }
        }  
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("File download complete");
    }
```

Comment: You should mention, if you want to do it in Win forms, Asp.Net or WPF.
I am short on time, so instead of answering, I'll leave you a link to read into, which explains it pretty well: http://www.devtoolshed.com/content/c-download-file-progress-bar.
Kind regards

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i cant figure out how to implement it with ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib?

Comment: Hmm, im using the UnzipFromStream so i can unzip "on the fly", with the method mentioned in the thread i would need to download the full file then unzip it....

Comment: @Serv So i managed to implement some of the articles suggestions however i still cant seem to get it to work...

Comment: dTotal is not `buffer.Length`, it is the size of your file.

Comment: so `double dTotal = (double)iSize;` ?

Comment: If i do the `double dTotal = (double)iSize;` its still not working... hmmm