# How to get a copy-percent when doing a stream.CopyTo(anotherStream) in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, streaming

I've got two streams and I wish to copy the contents from one, to another.

eg. `await stream1.CopyToAsync(stream2);`

Is there a way I can hook into an event so that for every .. say .. 10K bytes copied, I report something .. or for each 1% copied or something .. i get an event fired?

Looking at [some examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097324/c-sharp-stream-progress-just-like-downloadprogresschanged), they all suggest that I do NOT use the `CopyTo / CopyToAsync` method and instead revert back to the classic way of manually copying the data from `stream` => `stream2` manually, with a fixed array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd have to write your own method, perhaps as an extension method. It might look something like this:

```
public static async Task CopyToWithProgressAsync(this Stream source,
                                                 Stream destination,
                                                 int bufferSize = 4096,
                                                 Action<long> progress = null)
{
    var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    var total = 0L;
    int amtRead;
    do
    {
        amtRead = 0;
        while(amtRead < bufferSize)
        {
            var numBytes = await source.ReadAsync(buffer,
                                                  amtRead,
                                                  bufferSize - amtRead);
            if(numBytes == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            amtRead += numBytes;
        }
        total += amtRead;
        await destination.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, amtRead);
        if(progress != null)
        {
            progress(total);
        }
    } while( amtRead == bufferSize );
}
```

and you'd call it like:

```
stream1.CopyToWithProgressAsync(stream2, 
                                4096, 
                                amtCopied => Console.WriteLine(amtCopied))
```

Comment: Sweet - that's roughly what I ended up doing anyways (just wasn't sure if my temp code should actually be a legit answer). My 2x main differeneces were 1) firing a custom event with custom event args 2) using this while line `while ((bytesRead = await source.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)` instead. Ta!